# Embed Measured Column in graph Title in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

My dataset has changing date field

I want to dispaly in the graph title

> "Report as of 25 Sep 2019 14:21:48"

I have got the date in measure column called **LatestAccess**
which is equal to 25 Sep 2019 14:21:48

How to put it in the Title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until now, just possible with a workaround.
Deactivate your title and put a KPI Card visual on top of your chart. Drag and drop your measure into this KPI visual and you have your dynamic chart title.